# Create a vector of all values from all columns in a dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to create a vector of all values from a data frame. It seems like there must be a simple way of doing this but I can't find it.

```
# Dummy data
samples <- c('A','B','C', 'D')
var1 <- c(3, 5, NA, 5)
var2 <- c(4, 4, 2, 2)
var3 <- c(NA, 12, 12, 8)
df <- data.frame(var1,var2,var3,row.names=samples)
df
```

Desired output:

```
output <- c(3,5,NA,5,4,4,2,2,NA,12,12,8)
output
```

I've thought about looping through every column but haven't figured out how to iteratively add to a vector with each column. Something like this, but at the moment vals just contains the final column without adding each column to it:

```
for(i in 1:ncol(df)) {
  vals <- df[,i]
}
```

Maybe there's an easier way though. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can try `unlist`

```
output <- unlist(df,use.names = FALSE)
```

or

```
output <- unname(unlist(df))
```